# PHP: How to replace a specific tag and its endtag?

Tags: php, regex

I'm making a little chat, and I got a problem: I disabled HTML, but there must be a possibility to insert links. So I decided to mark them as

```
[LINK]http://anylink.com[/LINK].
```

Now, there could be multiple links like this in the text. How can I replace all of them with the following:

```
<a href="http://anyling.com">http://anylink.com</a>
```

Thank you for your help, I dont get it with the href tag :S

Comment: Links with `http://` as prefix are highlighted by most of the browsers as clickable links.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('%\[LINK\](.*?)\[/LINK\]%','<a href="$1">$1</a>', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = preg_replace('/\[LINK\](.+?)\[\/LINK\]/',"<a href=\"\\1\">\\1</a>",$input);
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the backref vars.

Comment: @Bllly, yes, yes you did. `$1` in double quote context will be treated as a variable, likely an undefined one. It will not be treated as a backreference. Use single quotes or call backreferences like this: `\\1`

Comment: @Kevin well you seem pretty keen on this point, so I will change it for you - but it works as it is. So my question - why does it work if it is wrong?

Comment: It's possible that it is a bug in the processing that allows the backreference to resolve before the variable reference. However, since the processing rules specifically state what I did above, I wouldn't rely on anything undocumented.

Comment: I looked it up: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php - says `replacement may contain references of the form \\n or (since PHP 4.0.4) $n, with the latter form being the preferred one.`